# getting started as a web developer

Tags: web-development, tools

I have over 10 years of programming experience building (Windows-based) *desktop* applications and utilities (VC++, C#, Python). My goal over the next year is to start transitioning to *web* application development. I want to teach myself the fundamental tools and technologies that would be considered essential for building professional, online, interactive, visually-stunning, data-driven web apps -- the kind described in Google's recently released ["Field Guide: Building Great Web Applications"](http://www.html5rocks.com/webappfieldguide/building-great-web-applications).

So my question is, what are the primary, most commonly-used technologies that seasoned professionals will need in their tool belt in the coming years? My plan was to start coming up to speed in Javascript, HTML5, & CSS, and then to do a deep dive into ASP.NET and Ajax, along with SQL DBs. (I was surprised to not be able to find a single book at Amazon with a broad, general scope like this, which caused me to start second-guessing this approach.)

So, seasoned professionals: am I on the right track? Are there some glaring omissions in my list? Or some unnecessary inclusions? I would welcome any book suggestions along these lines as well.